# Junos sub interface number limited to 16385

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

Is there a good reason why Junos limits its logical interfaces to 16385 ? i would love to use like the numbering schema to facilitate int.xxxxyyyy which helps with clearly identifying interfaces.

so is there a technical reason why this limitation exists ?

Comment: 2^14+1 is a bit of an odd limit. As such, it sounds like a bad programming choice. (I don't work on junos code, so I cannot prove it.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently unit numbers above 16K are reserved for special purpose use only. Not possible to allow these units for regular interfaces. Please contact your Juniper SE if you need higher number available to work on a enhancement request.